# gnuplot -formating unix timestamp on x axis as date - time

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following format of data:

```
1609257628 2
1609256682 4
1609255914 1
```

where the first column should be on x axis and is the unix timestamp. Is there any way to generate a readable date such as in format "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" and at the same time keeping the data points equally space on x axis?

I tried:

```
set format x "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
plot data  u 0:2:xticlabels(1) w l t
```

But it does nothing, plots the timestamp. So I tried more simply:

```
set format x "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
plot data u 1:2 w l
```

But i get

```
Bad format character
```

Anyway, the goal is to have the `plot using 0:2` but at the same time, x tics should be the corresponding time from the first column in some predefined format.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the points equally distant if you have timestamps? So, you want to display every timestamp in a readable format but equidistant? How many datapoints do you have, just 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation `help strftime` and try the following:

**Code:**

```
### plot timedata equidistant as xtic label
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1609257628 2
1609256682 4
1609255914 1
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"

plot $Data u 0:2:xtic(strftime(myTimeFmt,column(1))) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]